# &#233; é << charset

Tags: character-encoding

i want to display `&#233;`  é << this in xml not working out great wat shall be my charset ?

Comment: place \` \` around the &x233; to show it as `&x233;`

Answer (score 3):

use utf-8, Luke.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have control over the charset or are in doubt, using `&#xe9;` should also work. But yes, ideally you should use Unicode in your documents if you need to support multiple languages.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 (8-bit UCS), ISO 8859-1 (8-bit) (aka ISO Latin 1), ISO 10646 (16-bit UCS) [according to [this site](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)] allow to use `&#233` for the é.